# iPad Mini 64 Bit MD5 Hash

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have searched the stack for MD5 methods, and it seems as though most re-use the same code I'm posting below.  The code works perfect for iPhone, however when I go to run on iPad or the simulator i get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0` on the line `CC_MD5(str, strlen(str), result);`  Is this a 32 bit / 64 bit issue?  If so, can somebody explain how to adapt this code to support both?  What else could be different between the two platforms?

Thank you

```
- (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input
{
    const char* str = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(str, strlen(str), result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I call it like this -

```
NSString *pass = @"password";
NSString *passHash = [self md5:pass];
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in the 32-bit or 64-bit iOS Simulator. - (You should add a cast: `CC_MD5(str, (CC_LONG)strlen(str), result);` to avoid a compiler warning in 64-bit mode, but that does not explain the crash.)

Comment: Added the `CC_LONG`, but you're right.  Still doesn't fix it.  The method is placed directly on the view's .m file under my `@synthesize` line.  Any chance this has to be in it's own class?

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0 means the input string is null which makes no sense since you are calling it with a constant string. Did you include #import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h> in the file?

Comment: @ahwulf: That was also my first thought, but without that import file CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH would be unknown to the compiler.

Comment: Just for grins can you call NSLog(@"%s",str) right before the CC_MD5 call. Does this crash?

Comment: @ahwulf you were 100% correct.  For some strange reason, my string was null for the first loop - but only on the iPad.  I added a strlen if/else and problem solved.  If you turn that into an answer, I'll accept.  Hopefully someone else can find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this category of NSString, [from here](https://github.com/peturingi/Categories/blob/master/Categories/NSString/NSString+Checksum.m)

```
- (NSString *)md5 {
    if (!self) return nil;

    NSString *checksum = [NSString string];
    const char *cStr = [self cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned char buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_MD5(cStr, (CC_LONG)[self length], buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        checksum = [checksum stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x", buffer[i]]];
    }

    return checksum;
}
```